# NGINX + Flask + UWSGI static files and permissions

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

My `NGINX` configuration is quite simple as described on http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/uwsgi/#starting-your-app-with-uwsgi

```
location / { try_files $uri @yourapplication; }
location @yourapplication {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock;
}
```

I'm aware that you can add the following to the same configuration:

```
location /static {
   root /var/www;
}
```

and then `NGINX` will handle every thing in the folder `static/` however, sometimes it's required to be in the root directory `www.example.com/robots.txt` `www.example.com/favicon.ico` and so on. What would be an appropriate fix for the problem described above? I just moved from `PHP` and am very unfamiliar with putting up a nice `Python` based platform.

Also, it seems to only work when I launch my server manually;
`uwsgi -s /tmp/uwsgi.sock -w my_app:app --chown-socket=www:www`

What would be the appropriate way to automate this on startup? Hope this question is clear enough..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a couple of individual files you could just do the following in your nginx configuration:

```
location /**<your-filename-here>** { alias **<absolute-path-to-file>**; }
```

Example:

```
location /robots.txt { alias /var/www/static/robots.txt; }
```